# Cloning form and clone Fields in respective form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has some fields and 2 buttons one of which is to clone the complete form and other is intended to clone only form fields. I tried with `ng-repeat` but when I cloned the form then trying to clone fields in original form then it clones the fields in the cloned form also. How to restrict cloning in the duplicate form. 
This is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
      <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
        <hr />
        <form name="myForm" ng-init="name = form.name">
          <br>

          <div ng-repeat="user in users">
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.phone"/>
          </div><br>
          <button type="button" href="" ng-click="addUser()">Add user</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <input type="button" value="Create form" ng-click="createForm()" />
    </div>
  </body>    
</html>
```

and here is my `script.js

```
    angular.module("myApp", []).controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.forms = [{name: "form1"}];
    $scope.createForm = function(){
        $scope.forms.push({name: "form" + ($scope.forms.length + 1)});
    };
    $scope.saveForm = function(formScope){
        alert("Save called for " + formScope.name + ", myInputValue = " + formScope.myInputValue);            
    };
     $scope.users = [{name: 'John',phone: '098097770'},{name: 'Alice',phone: '765876598'}];
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.users.push({name: 'New user',phone: ''});
  };
  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert('Here are the users: ' + angular.toJson($scope.users));
  };
}]);
```

[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K8qRQCw6BQcF4IGumAI8?p=preview)

Comment: what do you mean by clone a form vs cloning form fields only? Did not get it

Comment: @RahulArora please check the plnkr demo. the problem is after cloning the form, I want to add user only in the respective form, not in both the form.

Comment: please check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working plnkr:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zK7ZMXV3zeWoBY0Lvu8m?p=preview)

Basically, you need to link the `user` with the `form` object so that its unique for each form.

There will be some changes to ng-repeat (the nested one) and one function call for addUser where you need to pass the index of the form for which user needs to be added

```
$scope.forms = [
      {
        name: "form1",
        users: [
            {name: 'John',phone: '098097770'},
            {name: 'Alice',phone: '765876598'}
          ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.createForm = function(){
        $scope.forms.push({
          name: "form" + ($scope.forms.length + 1),
          users: [
            {name: 'John',phone: '098097770'},
            {name: 'Alice',phone: '765876598'}
          ]
        });
    };
    $scope.saveForm = function(formScope){
        alert("Save called for " + formScope.name + ", myInputValue = " + formScope.myInputValue);            
    };

  $scope.addUser = function(index) {
    $scope.forms[index].users.push({name: 'New user',phone: ''});
  };
```